# Interpretation of C code to make the almost white pixels transparent - Value of HSV color model

Tags: c, rgb, hsv

I've the following C code to make the almost white pixels transparent, but i've some difficult to understand why the value is multiplied by 255. Can you tell me why please?

The pointer fish points to a bitmap in the memory; this bitmap has almost white pixels; instead fishp is a pointer which points to the part of the memory where i'd like to store the new bitmap.

```
int x, y, c;
int pink;
float hue, sat, val;
for (x = 0; x < fish - > w; x++)
  for (y = 0; y < fish - > h; y++) {
    c = getpixel(fish, x, y);
    rgb_to_hsv(getr(c), getg(c), getb(c), &
      hue, & sat, & val);
    val = val * 255;
    if (val >= 240) c = pink;
    putpixel(fishp, x, y, c);
  }
get_palette(pal);
save_bitmap("fishp.bmp", fishp, pal);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I suppose `val` is in the interval [0..1]. To be sure we need to see the `rgb_to_hsv`. And probably `putpixel` wants RGB values ranging from 0 to 255.

Comment: Hello @Jabberwocky yes val is in the range [0, 1]; who wrote the code confirmed me this, but he didn't tell me why val = val * 255

Comment: Then you have your answer.

Comment: What is the answer? Sorry, it's the first time I use HSV color model

Comment: My first comment is the answer.

Comment: `putpixel` wants RGB values from 0 to 255.

Comment: @Jabberwocky can you explain the reason by using different words please?

Comment: You *could* omit the `val = val * 255;` line and then make the following comparison `if (val >= 0.941176) c = pink;` but that would be far less clear to programmers, who will be familiar with the `0...255` range for pixel R/G/B values.

Comment: Hello @AdrianMole so with that statement (val = val * 255;) i'm mapping the value of val, belonging to the range [0, 1], on the "corresponding value" within the range [0, 255]? Corresponding value for me means for instance that if val is 10%=0.1, after the above statement, it will be the 10% of 255.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Exactly! The 'mapping' in that section of code serves no purpose other than to make it clear to any future programmer who should come across it what the threshold is, in units that they would be most familiar with. I could put up speed-limit signs in a town, in units of microparsecs per lunar month, but they wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @AdrianMole thank you very much for your useful replies.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Is the range truly `[0, 1]` or `[0, 1)`?  (1.0 not included in the 2nd range).

Comment: Hello @chux-ReinstateMonica the 1 is included.

Comment: @AdrianMole Limits like ‭0.0017 μps/lm? 

Answer (score 1):

> why the value is multiplied by 255?

In the [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) model, the `V` part, *value* has a numeric value in the [0.0 ... 1.0] range.

As many [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) models use primaries with integer values in the [0...255] range, scaling by 255 simply brings the *value* into a likewise range before the compare with 240.

Alternatively code could have been as below for a similar (and potentially faster) compare.

```
rgb_to_hsv(getr(c), getg(c), getb(c), &hue, & sat, & val);
// val = val * 255;
// if (val >= 240) c = pink;
if (val >= 240/255.0f) c = pink;
```

The key is that the threshold level of `240` implies an RGB model with 256 different primary levels and so the compare is done in those units.

---

Note: `pink` is never assigned a value, so code needs work else `if (val >= 240) c = pink;` is an issue.